# Client App using MS SQL Server 2000 periodically requires sa to reconnect client

Tags: windows, sql-server

I am now supporting a funky old app from 2000 that is an MS SQL Server 2000 client.  For some unknown reason, random staff members will periodically not be able to log in to the app.  I then have to login as sa and logout and then their credentials go back to working.  Any ideas on why this would happen?  I don't see a consistent cause/logic for when this occurs nor does it appear to be a NIC/power setting or idle timeout.  It could possibly have something to do with Windows 10 machines connecting to SQL Server 2000 but I'm more inclined to think it's a setting in SQL Server 2000.  I checked the disconnection setting and it appears to be set correctly.  Where would I find the log in Windows Server 2003 running MS SQL Server 2000 for when the disconnect occurs so that I can get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Hi, does all SP and patch is applied to rhe sql2000 ?